# Bulma Card - Error about dimensions: the card is too big

Tags: css, bulma

I was in the process of optimizing my site. I just integrated a Card a few minutes ago, from the Bulma framework.
Here is the doc of the element concerned https://bulma.io/documentation/components/card/

The problem is that it puts the card way too big for me, despite my attempts to reduce the "image is-4by3" and the "1980x960" by looking at the docs and other similar issues.

Here is the code and an image of the current result :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content">
texte ici
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That‘s because by default a card will take all the available width.
To solve this you can wrap it inside another element like [columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/) and use [size classes](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/) to get the right one for you.

An example with a half-sized and centered column :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="columns is-centered">
  <div class="column is-half">

    <!-- Your card code: --> 
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
            texte ici
            <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]